# dh_install: libnanomsg-dev missing files (usr/lib/*/lib*.a), aborting

Tags: debian, backports, fakeroot

I'm trying to backport `libnanomsg-dev` from `jessie` to `squeeze` and following [this tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation). Here's what I get:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
...
   dh_testroot -O--parallel
   dh_prep -O--parallel
   dh_installdirs -O--parallel
   dh_auto_install -O--parallel
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg'
test -z "/usr/lib" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib"
 ./doltlibtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libnanomsg.la '/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnanomsg.so.0.2.0 /home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib/libnanomsg.so.0.2.0
libtool: install: (cd /home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib && { ln -s -f libnanomsg.so.0.2.0 libnanomsg.so.0 || { rm -f libnanomsg.so.0 && ln -s libnanomsg.so.0.2.0 libnanomsg.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib && { ln -s -f libnanomsg.so.0.2.0 libnanomsg.so || { rm -f libnanomsg.so && ln -s libnanomsg.so.0.2.0 libnanomsg.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnanomsg.lai /home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib/libnanomsg.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnanomsg.a /home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib/libnanomsg.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib/libnanomsg.a
libtool: install: ranlib /home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib/libnanomsg.a
libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /usr/lib'
test -z "/usr/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/bin"
  ./doltlibtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c nanocat '/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/bin'
libtool: install: warning: `libnanomsg.la' has not been installed in `/usr/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/nanocat /home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/bin/nanocat
make  install-exec-hook
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg'
cd /home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/bin && \
      ln -s -f nanocat nn_push && \
      ln -s -f nanocat nn_pull && \
      ln -s -f nanocat nn_pub && \
      ln -s -f nanocat nn_sub && \
      ln -s -f nanocat nn_req && \
      ln -s -f nanocat nn_rep && \
      ln -s -f nanocat nn_surveyor && \
      ln -s -f nanocat nn_respondent && \
      ln -s -f nanocat nn_bus && \
      ln -s -f nanocat nn_pair
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg'
test -z "/usr/share/doc/nanomsg" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/share/doc/nanomsg"
test -z "/usr/share/man/man1" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/share/man/man1"
test -z "/usr/share/man/man3" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/share/man/man3"
test -z "/usr/share/man/man7" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/share/man/man7"
test -z "/usr/include/nanomsg" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/include/nanomsg"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/nn.h src/inproc.h src/ipc.h src/tcp.h src/pair.h src/pubsub.h src/reqrep.h src/pipeline.h src/survey.h src/bus.h '/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/include/nanomsg'
test -z "/usr/lib/pkgconfig" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib/pkgconfig"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libnanomsg.pc '/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/yuri/build/nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg'
   dh_install -O--parallel
dh_install: libnanomsg-dev missing files (usr/lib/*/lib*.a), aborting
make: *** [binary] Error 20
```

**UPD** Thanks to Stephen Kitt I was able to backport the package.

What exactly I did...

`debian/libnanomsg-dev.install`:

```
`usr/lib/*/lib*.a` -> `usr/lib/lib*.a`,<br>
`usr/lib/*/lib*.so` -> `usr/lib/lib*.so`,<br>
`usr/lib/*/pkgconfig/*.pc` -> `usr/lib/pkgconfig/*.pc`
```

`debian/libnanomsg0.install`:

```
`usr/lib/*/lib*.so.*` -> `usr/lib/lib*.so.*`
```

After that `fakeroot` finished successfully. But there were other issues:

I had a daemon running on `5555` port, so I [had to change `tests/tcp.c` test](https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg/issues/217) (that was before the issue with paths in `*.install` files):

```
#define SOCKET_ADDRESS "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555"
```

Additionally, `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` gave the following error:

```
   dh_autoreconf_clean -O--parallel
   dh_clean -O--parallel
 dpkg-source -b nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg
dpkg-source: info: using source format `3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building nanomsg using existing ./nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/test.ipc: device or socket is not allowed
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg/test-separation.ipc: device or socket is not allowed
dpkg-source: error: unrepresentable changes to source
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b nanomsg-0.4~beta+dfsg gave error exit status 2
```

So, I deleted `test.ipc` and `test-separation.ipc` files supposedly created by `fakeroot`, and it succeeded.

And there was [an issue with `debian-keyring`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181315/dh-install-libnanomsg-dev-missing-files-usr-lib-lib-a-aborting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Squeeze doesn't know (much) about multiarch, but the source package you're building uses multiarch paths (`usr/lib/*/lib*.a`, where the first `*` ends up being replaced by the multiarch triplet for the architecture you're building on). To fix the `dh_install` step you need to edit the appropriate `<package>.install` file in `debian` and change the paths to non-multiarch ones (in this instance, `usr/lib/lib*.a`). You'll probably also need to edit paths for `lib*.so` and remove the multiarch stanzas from `debian/control`...